# How to call AAR library methods?

Tags: xamarin, java-native-interface, xamarin.android

I'm trying to create a simple wrapper to [Application Insights Android SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Android)

I build the library in Android Studio which resulted in this debug [AAR file](https://incraved.cloudapp.net/owncloud/index.php/s/JYB7SW7OUhSLK6U) which I then added to a library binding project in Xamarin Studio.

However, when I reference it I have the namespace:

```
using Com.Microsoft.Applicationinsights.Library;
```

But it doesn't contain class ApplicationInsights which it should if it would match the java library it's wrapping.

I don't want a fancy complete CLR wrapper, I just want to call the "setup" method on that class which takes the app's Context as an argument, then be able to call simple tracking methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Java Binding library, add the AAR file then you can do things like:

```
_appInsights = JNIEnv.FindClass ("com/microsoft/applicationinsights/library/ApplicationInsights");
_methodSetup = JNIEnv.GetStaticMethodID(_appInsights, "setup",
            "(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/app/Application;Ljava/lang/String;)V");
```

Call setup on it:

```
    public static void Setup(Android.Content.Context context, Android.App.Application app, String key) {
        var c = new JValue(context);
        var a = new JValue(app);
        var s = new JValue(new Java.Lang.String(key));

        JNIEnv.CallStaticVoidMethod (_appInsights, _methodSetup, c, a, s);
    }
```